# How to scrape and extract links to n level and scrape the data again and map it to output in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am learning web crawling and scraping in python. I want to scrape data where in a site there are links, and inside those links there are more links. So I want to scrape data till predefined level n.
This is my basic code

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from webdrivermanager import GeckoDriverManager
import pickle
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
options = Options()

options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver",options=options)

web_url = 'https://spaceflightnow.com/'
driver.get("https://spaceflightnow.com/")
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
#section = soup.section
links=[]
for url in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
     links.append(urljoin(web_url,url.get('href')))
     #print(urljoin(web_url,url.get('href')))
links = list(filter(lambda x: x != web_url,links))
print(links)
```

This prints multiple links of first page. Now I want to click and go to all the links in subsequent level and scrape it again,getting more links inside. There is the possibility of same links getting displayed again internally from news feed. So what I want to know is what should be my approach to do it. I can understand I need a tree, but cannot figure out exactly how ?
Like I create a list inside list, but how to do it dynamically till n level ? and how to map it with the data saved in file ?? Can anyone help me with this ? maybe with a sample solution ?
Thank you :)

Comment: put code in function and run with arguments so you can do recurenction.

Comment: I know that, but lets say when I get link 1, then I will get more links, inside it, so do i get all of those again ? like for loop inside for ? or do I simple append it existing list and remove duplicate links and scrape data ? And should I check if links are present repeatedly ?

Comment: or create loop which get first link from list, visit it (using function which returns new links)  and add new links at the end - this way you can visit all links from list. And always check if new link doesn't exist on list so you will not visit the same link many times

Comment: first create function which gets one link, visit only this page and returns all links on this page - and it doesn't visit links which it found. And then you can use this in loop which control all links and it runs this function only with new link.

Comment: btw: you can assign `level` to every link and when you visit link with `level=n` then all new links would have `level=n+1`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, but I don't know how to do it as I am naive in python,so how to create the hashmap for it ? or exactly how to do it ? One more thing I can do is scrape till n level and extract all links and add it uniquely to list, then get them in for loop and scrape them without links, but how to check if list is not increasing ???

Comment: I made example which work without recursion - I would say it is similar to [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - but it doesn't control `level` because it would need function to check if new link is no list `[(url, level), (url, level),...)]`. Or it would need other list or better `set()` to keep only urls.

Comment: Is it possible to share your example code ?

Comment: I put code but maybe you should try to use framework [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) - it has option [DEPTH_LIMIT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit)

Comment: Yes, I was trying with scrapy with splash, but I had hard time with rendering ajax calls and javascript, so I chose selenium, now I need to to combine selenium and scrapy

Comment: there is exension [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)

Comment: Yes found it out recently, was trying to figure how to exactly write those middlewares, as many sites which I am parsing have authentication requirements, and I am unable to share session between two tools like request and selenium and scrapy and selenium, when it comes to ntlm login, so figuring it out exactly how to do it :)

Comment: it seems you have complex code so now rebuilding this with scrapy-selenium would make only more problems :) Good luck.

Comment: Kind off, but its segregated for different sites for now, so I am in more of a testing phase, so I do have the convenience  to make mistakes as of now :)

Answer (score 1):

I made example which work without recursion - I would say it is similar to [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm.

It keeps urls on list `[(url, level),...]` to control level and in `set()` to filter visited page. It also filters links to external pages.

Tested with Firefox.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# --- 

def get_links(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    links = []

    for new_url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
         new_url = new_url.get('href')
         new_url = urljoin(url, new_url) 
         links.append(new_url)

    return links

# ---

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver",options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# ---

domain = 'https://spaceflightnow.com/' # to filter external links
start_url = 'https://spaceflightnow.com/'
max_level = 2

links_visited = set([start_url])  # to test visited links
links_with_levels = [(start_url, 0)] # to control levels 

# ---

for link, level in links_with_levels:
    if level >= max_level:
        print('skip:', level, link)
        continue

    print('visit:', level, link)

    links = get_links(driver, link)

    print('found:', len(links))
    links = list(set(links) - links_visited)
    print('after filtering:', len(links))

    level += 1

    for new_link in links:
        if new_link.startswith(domain): # filter external links
            links_visited.add(new_link)
            links_with_levels.append( (new_link, level) )

# ---

for link, level in links_with_levels:
    print('skip:', level, link)
```

Comment: Does this code scrape link upto second level ? and I need to scrape further ?

Comment: change `max_level` to set other level. But `BFS` first get all links on second level before it goes to next level so it take time before it starts next level.

Comment: Sure,will try and let you know, thank you a lot for all the help btw :)